# PHP MongoDate Format similar to JS Date to use in Mongoose Query

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoose

I have a web application where i use PHP and NodeJS both on the server side. I have situation where i create a user record in PHP and use NodeJS for reporting and all that.

It was seems to be working okay with lot of data but now with some of the records the date format is not good. I mean when i run the query to get records in a certain date range some of the results are missing which supposed to be included, after lot of debugging, I got to know that the date format is different.

I do use `new MongoDate()` when creating a record and in Mongoose Schema i have field type `Date`. I need somebody who can guide me to get exactly similar date format in PHP which can be used in Mongoose query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it to use `moment` on `nodejs` and `php` both sides and it worked well. Plus for those who are looking for timezone option go with `moment-timezone`